# How to find the characters of the second word in a phrase using indexOf(); and char method?

Tags: java

I want to find the characters of the second word in a phrase using indexOf(); method and charAt();
You have to assume that the phrase will always have 3 words and that the second words will always have 5 letters. 
Sample input is "The white horse" ------> output is: Second word is 'white'

I have to achieve this without loops, built-in methods of java like substring, split...etc
Here is my attempt but it keeps giving me one character:
It should be constant that means it should always be 5, I think its the use of a print statement 5 times

```
else if (option == 4){
            int start = phrase.indexOf(' ');
            int end = phrase.indexOf(' ', start + 1);
            int length = end - start - 1;
            char n = phrase.charAt(length+2);
                System.out.print("Second word is '"+n+"'");
    }
```

Comment: Of course it gives you one character. `n` is a `char`. Instead, use `String.substring()` to get the second word.

Comment: Can't use substring or any loops

Comment: No loops? Then you have to write five times `System.out.print(...)`.

Comment: The rules seem arbitrary. What is the full context for this? What are you trying to learn atm?

Comment: @TiberiuDorianMoşescu Not arbitrary at all. It's obviously an assignment to test if they can use what they have learned so far, so they are not allowed to use certain features, to force them to use the methods they are being tested on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting the requirements, and highlighting the important ones:

> Find the characters of the **second word** in a phrase using **`indexOf()`** method and **`charAt()`**. You have to assume that the phrase will always have 3 words and that the second word will **always have 5 letters**.
>
> Can't use `substring` or any loops.

Seems you have to do it like this:

```
String phrase = "The white horse";

int idx = phrase.indexOf(' ');
System.out.println("Second word is '" + phrase.charAt(idx + 1)
                                      + phrase.charAt(idx + 2)
                                      + phrase.charAt(idx + 3)
                                      + phrase.charAt(idx + 4)
                                      + phrase.charAt(idx + 5) + "'");
```

Or like this:

```
String phrase = "The white horse";

int idx = phrase.indexOf(' ');
System.out.print("Second word is '");
System.out.print(phrase.charAt(idx + 1));
System.out.print(phrase.charAt(idx + 2));
System.out.print(phrase.charAt(idx + 3));
System.out.print(phrase.charAt(idx + 4));
System.out.print(phrase.charAt(idx + 5));
System.out.println("'");
```

Answer (score -1):

Simple solution:

```
String[] words = phrase.split(" ");
System.out.print("Second word is '"+words[1]+"'");
```

Solution using only charAt() and indexOf()

```
int start = phrase.indexOf(' ');
int end = phrase.indexOf(' ', start + 1);

System.out.print("Second word is '");
for (int i=start+1; i<end; i++) {
   System.out.print(phrase.charAt(i));
}
System.out.print("'");
```

Comment: If OP can't use substring, but only indexOf() and charAt(), then split() is certainly off limit. --- From [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61486419/how-to-find-the-characters-of-the-second-word-in-a-phrase-using-indexof-and-c#comment108767139_61486419): *Can't use substring or any **loops**.*

Comment: "No loops" is not in the initial problem statement. Also, can you provide an answer without loops?

Comment: [Answer without loops](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61486777/5221149).

Answer (score -1):

use this to achieve the second word :

```
final String ans = input.split(" ")[1];
```

or try repeating your code 5 times with icreasing your index.

Comment: If OP can't use `substring`, but only `indexOf()` and `charAt()`, then `split()` is certainly off limit.